# Strange behaviour of keyboard after a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator

I have a bash script file that was working properly. I added some lines to that file and started debugging my bash script using bash debugger `bashdb`.
`bashdb` is working properly without any problem. Until I reached to following command line:

```
mapfile -t newdirs < <( ( for i in "${newpath[@]:$start:$((stop-start))}"; do echo "$i"; done )|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: "; ORS=$'\n';} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))"\n";}')
```

it is line # 116 in my script. Here is steps I go through:

```
$ bashdb myscript.sh
bash debugger, bashdb, release 4.2-0.8

Copyright 2002, 2003, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011 Rocky Bernstein
This is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.

(/path/to/myscript.sh:20):
20: if [ -n "$1" ]
bashdb<0> c 116
One-time breakpoint 1 set in file /path/to/myscript.sh, line 116.
(/path/to/myscript.sh:116):
116:          mapfile -t newdirs < <( ( for i in "${newpath[@]:$start:$((stop-start))}"; do echo "$i"; done )|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: "; ORS=$'
';} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))"
";}')
bashdb<1> s
(/path/to/myscript.sh:116):
116:          mapfile -t newdirs < <( ( for i in "${newpath[@]:$start:$((stop-start))}"; do echo "$i"; done )|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: "; ORS=$'
';} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))"
";}')
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: "; ORS=$'
';} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))"
";}'
(/path/to/myscript.sh:116):
116:          mapfile -t newdirs < <( ( for i in "${newpath[@]:$start:$((stop-start))}"; do echo "$i"; done )|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: "; ORS=$'
';} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))"
";}')
for i in "${newpath[@]:$start:$((stop-start))}"
bashdb<2> bashdb<(2)>
```

After that my keyboard does not work properly in the terminal window that the `bashdb` is running. I have to press each key two or more times or even hold it for a few seconds to be echoed on Terminal windows. For examples i press three times <kbd>q</kbd>, but it echos just one `q` letter. After that I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> one time and it shows:

```
** Undefined command "qqq". Try "help".
```

Sometimes it does not displays the key i pressed at all (even after holding it for few seconds) and after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> it shows:

```
** Undefined command "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq". Try "help".
```

It acts like that my keyboard hardware is damaged or dusty, but it is not. It works properly in other windows!

This strange behavior is only in that terminal window and in other windows keyboard is working properly. If success to quit from `bashdb` by pressing <kbd>q</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the strange behavior remains inside that Terminal. The only solution is to close that Terminal windows and re-open a new Terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. I tried many times and this strange behavior occurs exactly on line 116 of my script.

**NOTE:**
I found that it is not related directly to that line of my script. This strange behavior also may occur if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+C in `bashdb`.

Comment: Ignore what your terminal does or doesn't show. To exit bashdb, type `q` exactly once and press `Enter` exactly once. Then type this command (again ignoring what you see or don't see on the terminal): `stty sane` and press `Enter`.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that solves the problem without need to close Terminal window. But why this problem occurs and how to prevent?

Comment: If you output certain control characters to the terminal, it can get broken like that. The only way to prevent this is to avoid outputting unknown binary content to the terminal.

Comment: Your `awk` is wrong: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: "; ORS=$'\n';} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))"\n";}'`. The single quote in `ORS=$'` closes the first single quote, and the single quote after `\n` opens a new single quote… which is never closed.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf But it works! Also, some times this strange behavior does not occur!

Comment: It doesn't work, otherwise you wouldn't be asking a question about it `:)`. Anyways, your `awk` line is wrong and is strictly equivalent to `awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: "; ORS=$n;} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))"\n";}'` (see with `ORS=$n`, which is not what you want). Now I'm not saying this is why you obtain your error (that's why I'm leaving a comment).

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that `bashdb` isn't interacting well with the process substitution.